# find last row where at least one column is not NA

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I have an object that has all NAs in each column after a certain number of rows. Some of the columns also have NAs prior to this point. I want to get the row index of the last row where at least one column has data in it. Here is some sample data to work with:

**EDIT:** For robustness, I've added NAs in the second row, following @G. Grothendieck comments. In this case, the output should still be 5.

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = c(1:3,rep(NA, 2)))
df <- rbind(df, rep(NA, ncol(df)), rep(NA, ncol(df)))
df[2,] <- NA

df
   a  b  c
1  1  6  1
2 NA NA NA
3  3  8  3
4  4  9 NA
5  5 10 NA
6 NA NA NA
7 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Also could consider `max(sapply(df, function(x) max(which(!is.na(x)))))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) na.trim** This removes rows from the bottom which are all NA and then returns the number of rows left:

```
library(zoo)
nrow(na.trim(df, "right", is.na = "all"))
## [1] 5
```

**2) Base R**  We can replace each non-NA with its row number and then take the maximum of those numbers:

```
max(ifelse(is.na(df), NA, row(df)), na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 5
```

**2a)** If all the entries are numeric, as in the question, then this could be shortened to:

```
max(row(df) + 0 * df, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

**[1]** We can use `rowSums` to create a logical vector and wrap with `which` to return the index

```
tail(which(rowSums(!is.na(df)) > 0), 1)
#[1] 5
```

---

**[2]** Or another option is `lengths`. after removing the `NA` in each column

```
max(lengths(lapply(df, na.omit)))
#[1] 5
```

This option could fail in some edge cases as @G Grothendieck mentioned in the comments i.e.  when a particular row is all NA before the last set of NA rows

---

**[3]** Or another option is `which` with `arr.ind` option on a logical matrix

```
max(which(!is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)[,1])
#[1] 5
```

**[4]** or with `row` and `is.na`

```
max(row(df) * NA^is.na(df), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 5
```

NOTE: All approaches use **base R** and requires no ***additional packages***

Comment: (2) gives 4 instead of 5 for df[2, ] <- NA

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yes, thanks, that is an edge case I didn't consider

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
nrow(df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), ])

# [1] 5
```

Note that this only works if the rows with all missing values are at the very end of your data frame, e.g. it would fail with `df[2, ] <- NA` as mentioned by @G.Grothendieck.

Another option for tackling these edge cases would be:

```
sum(cumsum(rowSums(df[rev(rownames(df)),], na.rm = TRUE)) != 0)

# [1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck, indeed - will mention that.